# How to differentiate alarm signal of different threads?

Tags: multithreading, thread-sleep

I got to implement user level thread library. My problem is with sleep function.

am waking a thread which was slept using  SIGALRM signal generated by ualarm function.
when multiple threads were set to sleep with different sleep times how can I identify when the timer fires which thread must I remove from sleep queue....??
How to differentiate alarm signal of different threads??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal handler is called from the context of the target thread. Hence, thread-specific storage works as expected (I tested it on Linux and Solaris). From the signal handler use [the unix self-pipe](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) trick to communicate from the signal handler back to the thread:

```
__thread int signal_pipe; // The write end.

extern "C" void signal_handler(int signo, siginfo_t*, void*)
{
    if(!signal_pipe) // programming error: signal is being delivered to a wrong thread.
        abort();
    unsigned char signo_byte = static_cast<unsigned>(signo);
    // standard unix self pipe trick
    write(signal_pipe, &signo_byte, 1);
}
```

Each thread using this signal handler must create its own pipe and initialize `signal_pipe` with the write end of that pipe.